# Check missing columns in SQL table before copying into another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have 1000s of tables like ABC_0001, ABC_0002, ABC_0003 and so on.. and I would like to do 2 things:

1. From each table, I am looking to copy columns x, y and z in new table.
   However not all tables have all 3 columns e.g. ABC_0001 is missing column x, ABC_0002 is missing y and z or any other combinations.
   How can I check if the columns is present in selected table and if not assign default value say "0".
2. There are actually many variables instead of x, y, z which needs to be copied from all the tables into new table. I have this list in a separate table (say TABLE_COL_NAME with variable name, var type e.g. a int, b varchar(200) and so on) and this will change in future, hence I would like to create NEW_TABLE and assign variables in @VarNames dynamically using TABLE_COL_NAME.

Thanks Annamalai for helping with below base code. cheers.
Edit: This is SSMS v18.7

> ```
> DECLARE 
>  @TableName VARCHAR(500)
> ,@Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
> ,@Id INT
> ,@VarNames VARCHAR(8000)
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NEW
>
> CREATE TABLE TABLE_NEW (x int, y varchar(200), z varchar(500))
>     
> SET @VarNames = 'x, y, z'
>  
> DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR 
> FOR 
> SELECT 
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC) Id
> ,TABLE_NAME 
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
> WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
> AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ABC%'
>
> OPEN Table_Cursor  
> FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Id,@TableName 
>
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
> BEGIN  
>      IF(@Id = 1)
>         BEGIN
>             
>             SET @Sql = @Sql + 'SELECT ' + @VarNames + 'FROM '+@TableName ----Modify the columns based on your column names
>             SELECT @SQL
>         END
>      ELSE
>         BEGIN
>             SET @Sql = @Sql + ' UNION ALL SELECT '+ @VarNames + 'FROM '+@TableName --Modify the columns based on your column names
>         END
>
>      FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Id,@TableName
> END 
>
> CLOSE Table_Cursor  
> DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
>
> INSERT INTO TABLE_NEW 
> EXEC (@Sql)
> ```

Comment: I guess this is SQL Server? Please tag the version. You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects to query whether a table has certain columns or not. I suggest you go through the code you've been provided line by and line and try and understand it because all of the building blocks are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lousy data model.  It looks like you need some code to help fix it.

You can construct a `union all` statement as follows.  First, construct the appropriate logic for the column names for each table:

```
select 'select ' +
       coalesce(max(case when c.column_name = 'x' then c.column_name end), 'null as x') + ', ' +
       coalesce(max(case when c.column_name = 'y' then c.column_name end), 'null as y') + ', ' +
       coalesce(max(case when c.column_name = 'z' then c.column_name end), 'null as z') + ' ' +
       'from ' + c.table_name
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name like 'abc_%';
group by c.table_name;
```

Then construct the SQL statement:

```
select string_agg(sql,
                  '
union all
'
                  ) 
from (select 'select ' +
                   coalesce(max(case when c.column_name = 'x' then c.column_name end), 'null as x') + ', ' +
                   coalesce(max(case when c.column_name = 'y' then c.column_name end), 'null as y') + ', ' +
                   coalesce(max(case when c.column_name = 'z' then c.column_name end), 'null as z') + ' ' +
                   'from ' + c.table_name as sql
      from information_schema.columns c
      where table_name like 'abc_%'
      group by c.table_name
     ) t;
```

You can then assign this to a variable and run it.  [A SQL Fiddle illustrates this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fff65ea1496145064a107aeae6360602).

Note that the above is intentionally simplified to focus on the steps, not taking into account:

- The `_` in the table name is a wildcard for `like`.
- The schema name as well as the table name.
- Column names that need to be escaped.

You can also use the constructed SQL to create a view rather than execute it directly.